# Can't :hover whole line of a table

Tags: html, css, html-table, hover

When I pass mouse over a cell of the table, I want to highlight the whole line! But with the code that I have all I can to highlight just one cell! This is my table:

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th>Title1</th> 
            <th>Title2</th> 
            <th>Title3</th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td>Bach</td> 
            <td>42526</td> 
            <td>Dec 10, 2002 5:14 AM</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Doe</td> 
            <td>243155</td> 
            <td>Jan 18, 2007 9:12 AM</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Conway</td> 
            <td>35263</td>
            <td>Jan 18, 2001 9:12 AM</td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

and css is

```
   /*Table sort*/
table.tablesorter {
    font-family:arial;
    background-color: #e6EEEE;
    font-size: 8pt;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
    background-color: #e6EEEE;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    font-size: 8pt;
    padding: 4px;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
table.tablesorter tbody td {
    color: #3D3D3D;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    vertical-align: top;
}
table.tablesorter tbody tr.odd td {
    background-color:#F0F0F6;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    /*background-color: #8dbdd8;*/
    background-color: #e6EEEE;
}
table.tablesorter tbody tr :hover {
    background: #8dbdd8;
}
```

What is missing in my CSS to highlight whole line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply need to remove a space in your selector:

```
table.tablesorter tbody tr:hover
                       /* ^ space was removed */
```

---

Because you left a comment saying "it's not working":

See here, where it works: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Pe6Xe/

---

Per your edit, this will work:

```
table.tablesorter tbody tr:hover td {
    background: #8dbdd8;
}
```

The issue was that the `background-color` on your `td`s was covering the changed `background-color` on the `tr` hover.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Pe6Xe/1/

Comment: not working... without space stops highlighting even one cell

Comment: But you agree that it works in my jsFiddle demonstration? This fact means that you've omitted some vital information in your original question.

Comment: yeah.. i see it working there... but another css code related to table sorting. this may affect :hover?

Comment: Yes, there must be something else affecting it. Is there any JavaScript involved here? More information is required to solve this. A link to a live page would be the fastest way. If that's not an option, you could try showing your entire CSS.

Comment: I've just updated css...and as you can see it's not working on that link. I don't know if I can combine tablesorter and highlighting on the same table

Comment: I find that using chrome developer tools (or firebug in firefox) to look at what styles are being applied to an element really helps figure these kinds of situations out quickly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the space between tr and :hover.  As in, change this:

```
tr :hover
```

to:

```
tr:hover
```

Comment: Which browsers are you targeting?  It works in webkit/FF here: http://jsfiddle.net/PugsZ/

Comment: Yeah, my sample works in Chrome.  Did you try the link that I posted?

Comment: Yes, i did.. and it's working there. I'll try to post all my css code there.. thank you for link

Comment: Try removing the background color from your td classes